# Create multiple db tables with nodejs for postgresql

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm working on a project with **nodejs and postgresqlDB**.
What I want to do is, to setup a schema with some tables, which have also foreign keys to each other in it. The **problem** on my actual solution is, that the order of the queries differs each time I start the app. So when it comes, that e.g. the attributeTable is created before schema, there's logically an error. But how can I save the order of the queries, so that tables and schema is created in the order I want?

I tried to put dependent tables in the .then-clause, but this did not work better.

```
        function getDB(callback) {
            let pgp = require('pg-promise')({
                // Initialization Options
            });

           // fetches uri for queries       
           var dbPostgres = pgp(returnUriToDB());

           // sql-queries in some constants
           let createSchema = createSchema;
           let attributeTable = createAttributeTable;
           let objectGroupTable = createObjectGroupTable;

           dbPostgres.query(createSchema)
                    .then(function () {
                        console.log('+++++ schema exists or was successfully created');
                        return;
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err);
                        console.log('----- schema could not be initialized :(');
                        return;
                    });

           dbPostgres.query(attributeTable)
                    .then(function () {
                        console.log('+++++ attributeTable exists or was successfully created');
                        return;
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err);
                        console.log('attributeTable could not be initialized :(');
                        return;
                    });

           dbPostgres.query(objectGroupTable)
                    .then(function () {
                        console.log('+++++ objectGroupTable exists or was successfully created');
                        return;
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err);
                        console.log('----- objectGroupTable could not be created :(');
                        return;
                    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those calls `dbPostgres.query` are asynchronous. Check Promises.

```
dbPostgres.query(createSchema)
    .then(function() {
        console.log('+++++ schema exists or was successfully created');
        return;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log('----- schema could not be initialized :(');
        return;
    })
    .then(dbPostgres.query(attributeTable))
    .then(function() {
        console.log('+++++ attributeTable exists or was successfully created');
        return;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log('attributeTable could not be initialized :(');
        return;
    })
    .then(dbPostgres.query(objectGroupTable))
    .then(function() {
        console.log('+++++ objectGroupTable exists or was successfully created');
        return;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log('----- objectGroupTable could not be created :(');
        return;
    });
```

Using awaits (more readable)

```
async function whatever() {
    await dbPostgres.query(createSchema).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log('----- schema could not be initialized :(');
    });
    console.log('+++++ schema exists or was successfully created');

    await dbPostgres.query(attributeTable).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log('attributeTable could not be initialized :(');
    });
    console.log('+++++ attributeTable exists or was successfully created');

    await dbPostgres.query(objectGroupTable).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log('----- objectGroupTable could not be created :(');
        return;
    });
    console.log('+++++ objectGroupTable exists or was successfully created');

}

// you can use async functions like promises (with then-catch schema)

whatever.then(..).catch(..).then(..);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, for that very fast answer. I put all those dbPostgres.query()-functions in a async setupSchema-Function with awaits, as you've proposed. And I will call it from the position in my origin code, where the queries-part starts. Unfortunately I have a Syntax-Error now: "Parsing error: Unexpected token function" because of the async and await parts. Have I missed something?

Comment: I'm really not sure, but whats your Node version? A quick google search says node 6.7 is required to use async await natively. Try to swtich to then-catch schema or update your node version (`sudo npm install -g n && sudo n stable`).

Comment: OK, I just run it and it works. I don't know, apparently it's just the ide editor, which doesn't like the async and awaits. (the version is 8.x). Thank you very much for your help! :)